# Laravel match and any method

Tags: php, html, laravel, post, get

I´m working with Laravel building a web app. This app will contain a FORM that only asks a name of a requisite of a client that will be added in to a database. I´m trying to obtain the ID of the client by 'GET' method and the title of the requisite by 'POST' method. I´ve tryied to use 'MATCH' metchod but that brings me errors.

These is the code in the view:

```
<form action="{{ route('folders.store') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('match')
...
</form>
```

These in the web:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'folders/store', [PartnerController::class, 'store'])-> name('folders.store');
```

and these in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        @dump($request);
        return $request;
    }
```

In the last I´m just trying to verify want I´m doing. jaja.
Thank you.

I´ve tryied using method 'any', with no results.
I´ve changed the 'post' to 'get' method but it´s not a really secure option.

I think I don´t really understand what I´m doing at all.

Comment: What is the error? Also, I hope you're not trying to trigger both GET and POST in a single request

Comment: match method of route means any request with post or get http varb . but why you are using this? you only need to use post method to store data

Comment: I was trying to obtain the ID of the partner by the 'GET' method because I needed to link the two tables in the database. The 'partners' table and the 'folders' table. folders table has its own id and as a secondary key uses the partner´s id. Anyways... I think I was doing nonsense hahah sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you're out of conventions but anyway if you're user logs in you can get the id with Auth::id(), but if not, go with this

```php
Route::post('folders/store/{$id}', [PartnerController::class, 'store'])-> name('folders.store');
```

then in form

```
<form action="{{ route('folders.store',$id) }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
...
</form>
```

and in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
    {
        dd($request);
        return $request;
    }
```